# Neo4j Index ingored in Where clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a neo4j database, containing nodes with label **User**. An index is made on the User.user_id property.

Executing the following query does use the index:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.user_id = 1234
RETURN u
```

[image]

But, when modifying the query as follows, the index is totally ignored spanning all records to retrieve the required one:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE 1234 is null OR u.user_id = 1234
RETURN u
```

[image]

The use case of such a query is filter using multiple optional parameters, e.g:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE ({user_id} is null OR u.user_id = {user_id})
AND   ({status} is null or u.status = {status})
AND   ({name} is null or u.name = {})
RETURN u
```

How can we explain this behavior in neo4j, and what are the potential fixes without workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

The query plan is constructed independent of parameter evaluation (remember query plans are cached and reused, so it's not on a per-query basis), so during planning of a query like this:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE ({user_id} is null OR u.user_id = {user_id})
...
```

there is no way to know before actually executing whether an index lookup or a label scan should be used, so it defaults to a label scan operation.

As a workaround you may be able to use [APOC conditional procedures](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/conditionals/) which lets you execute conditional Cypher:

```
CALL apoc.case([$user_id is not null, "MATCH (u:User {user_id : $user_id} RETURN u", $name is not null, "MATCH (u:User {name:$name}) RETURN u", $status is not null, "MATCH (u:User {status:$status}) RETURN u"], "MATCH (u:User) RETURN u", {user_id:$user_id, name:$name, status:$status}) YIELD value
WITH value.u as u
WHERE ($status is null or u.status = $status)
AND   ($name is null or u.name = $name)
...
```

You do need to keep the status and name checks in case the first condition was triggered allowing a user_id index lookup, or in case the second condition was triggered allowing a name index lookup, you still want to filter on the rest.

Alternately, you can handle this in your code which is using the driver, either assembling or selecting the query you want to run based upon the parameters you have. That would make for less complicated and more efficient Cypher.

Comment: Please, can you explain why the index on user_id was ignored when adding this {user_id} is null as an OR operand , although there is an explicit where condition for this u.user_id = {user_id} ?

I know it is not related to parameter evaluation, even hard-coded numbers will produce the case.